# curve of $(x^2+y^2)^2=2(x^2-y^2)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

The diagram shows the curve $(x^2+y^2)^2=2(x^2-y^2)$ and one of its maximum points $M$. Find the coordinates of $M$.

My attempt.

Differentiate the equation and I got

$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{x(x^2+y^2-1)}{y(x^2+y^2+1)}$

How should I proceed?

Comment: The curve looks like an infinity symbol. What do you mean by a maximum point? The two points with the maximum value of $y$?

Comment: Apart from almagest's comment, I suggest that you pass to polar coordinates. It is the Lemniscate of Bernoulli.

Answer (score 1):

I think you take the top part set it to zero $x(x^2+y^2-1)=0$, since thats how you get the critical numbers. Then you have :

$x=0$ or $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$
plug y back into original formula and solve to get something like 
 $x=\pm \sqrt{\frac{3}{4}}$ so max would be at one of those $x$ values.

Answer (score 1):

HINT.-You have a closed curve, symmetrical with respect to the two axes (a lemniscate indeed) and you have the alternative of take the explicit form for $y$ solving a quadratic equation; you have
$$y^4+2(x^2+1)y^2+(x^4-2x^2)=0$$ By symmetry you can take only the positive signs in solving so you have 
$$y=\left(-x^2-1+\sqrt{4x^2+1}\right)^{\frac 12}$$
$$y'=\frac{-x+\frac{2x}{\sqrt{4x^2+1}}}{\sqrt y}$$

Hence you get for the maximun $$x=\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$$ Thus $$y=\frac 12$$